# Custom control expose child binadable property in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The situation is the following:

I have created a custom control which contains among other children a ImageView. 
I want to be able to bind a property (IsVisible) of this child view from XAML when using the custom control but am not sure how I can expose this property in the parent custom control.

I want to set something like this (where IsLeftImageVisible should be the exposed child control property):

```
<controls:StepIndicator IsLeftImageVisible="{Binding IsValid}" />
```

For now i've done something like this, but I don't really like it:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty IsLeftButtonVisibleProperty = 
    BindableProperty.Create<StepIndicator, bool>
       (x => x.IsLeftImageVisible, true, propertyChanged: ((
        bindable, value, newValue) =>
    {
        var control = (StepIndicator)bindable;
        control.ImageLeft.IsVisible = newValue;
    }));

    public bool IsLeftImageVisible
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsLeftImageVisibleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsLeftImageVisibleProperty, value); }
    }
```

Is there a way to do this more elgantly?

Comment: Why isn't this elegant? This is how you create a `BindableProperty`.

Although I wonder if you really need a bindable property since you are not using it with a binding in your example code.

If you are not going to bind to it, just create a normal property and in the set show or hide your image. Maybe that will look more elegant to you?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @GeraldVersluis - of course I'm going to bind the property, this was just for an example

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way of doing this:

- Change LeftImage to private field
- Use OnElementPropertyChanged (from renderer) or OnPropertyChanged (from shared class)

From renderer:

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == StepIndicator.IsLeftButtonVisibleProperty.PropertyName)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

From shared class:

```
protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    if (propertyName == StepIndicator.IsLeftButtonVisibleProperty.PropertyName)
    {
        this.imageLeft.IsVisible = newValue;
    }
}
```

Or subscribe to PropertyChanged event:

```
PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => {
    if (e.PropertyName == StepIndicator.IsLeftButtonVisibleProperty.PropertyName) { // do something }
};
```